# Sorting a Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, sorting

I am new to PHP.  I have a PHP array that is two dimensional.  The "inner" array has a value that I want to sort on.

For example:

```
$myarray[1]['mycount']=12
$myarray[2]['mycount']=13
$myarray[3]['mycount']=9
```

I want to sort the "inner" array in descending order.

So the results for the following will be 13, 12, 9

```
foreach ($myarray as $myarr){
  print $myarr['mycount']
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`usort();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort by a user-defined comparison.

```
// Our own custom comparison function
function fixem($a, $b){
  if ($a["mycount"] == $b["mycount"]) { return 0; }
  return ($a["mycount"] < $b["mycount"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Our Data
$myarray[0]['mycount']=12
$myarray[1]['mycount']=13
$myarray[2]['mycount']=9

// Our Call to Sort the Data
usort($myArray, "fixem");

// Show new order
print "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: I am getting the following error "sort() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given"

Comment: I named the sort function sort which is already taken.  I now changed it to cmp.  I am getting a different error: usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function

Comment: I found another post on stackoverflow. I needed to invoke array( $this, 'compare_label' ).  Thanks everything works now!

Answer (score 4):

Check [`array_multisort`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)