# Sorting an array with DateTime strings?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can i sort efficiently this array (recent items first) on `end_time` value in PHP?

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'value' => int 4
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-20T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array
      'value' => int 0
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-21T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  2 => 
    array
      'value' => int 5
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-22T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  3 => 
    array
      'value' => int 4
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-23T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  4 => 
    array
      'value' => int 7
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-24T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Two-Dimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970207/sorting-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`usort`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function? It lets you define a callback function to compare two values. So I'm suggesting something along these lines:

```
function compare_func($a, $b)
{
    // CONVERT $a AND $b to DATE AND TIME using strtotime() function
    $t1 = strtotime($a["end_time"]);
    $t2 = strtotime($b["end_time"]);

    return ($t2 - $t1);
}

usort(main_array, "compare_func");
```

Comment: +1 for actually comparing as timestamps.  Your complicated logic isn't necessary though.  Just return $t2 - $t1.  Its value will be either positive, negative or 0 anyway, which is fine for sorting.

Comment: @GordonM Why not do a string comparison? If all times are the same time zone (UTC) then wouldn't this be more efficient? And just use [`strcmp()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) as the comparison function.

Comment: @w3d: [tag:micro-optimization] is bad, and as the rules for string sorting are quite different for the ones for date/time sorting it's not certain you'll even get the correct results. Using strtotime makes it very clear that you're expecting timestamps and that you're sorting based on temporal data.

Answer (score 6):

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['end_time']) - strtotime($b['end_time']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){ 
    return (strtotime ($a ['end_time']) 
          - strtotime ($b ['end_time'])) 
          * -1; 
});
```

Comment: Why multiply for `-1`? After reading `usort` documentation i've found that compare function should return a negative number if `$a` precedes `$b`, so multiplication is not necessary - i think.

Comment: It's for reserve order - recent first.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function sort_datewise($x, $y) {
    $t1 = strtotime($x['end_time']);
    $t2 = strtotime($y['end_time']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'sort_datewise');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function like this:

```
$arr=array();
$arr[] = array('valeu' => "4", 'end_time' => '2012-01-20T08:00:00+0000');
$arr[] = array('valeu' => "0", 'end_time' => '2012-01-21T08:00:00+0000');
$arr[] = array('valeu' => "5", 'end_time' => '2012-01-22T08:00:00+0000');
$arr[] = array('valeu' => "4", 'end_time' => '2012-01-23T08:00:00+0000');
$arr[] = array('valeu' => "7", 'end_time' => '2012-01-24T08:00:00+0000');
print_r($arr);
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $ta = strtotime($a['end_time']);
    $tb = strtotime($b['end_time']);
    return ($ta - $tb);
}
uasort($arr, 'cmp');
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: You're still dealing with strings at this point, so it might not produce very good results (can you even subtract strings in PHP with the - operator?).  You should generate timestamps from the end_time strings and compare those instead.

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be `$ta = strtotime($a['end_time']);` not sure how I typed it without strtotime call.

Answer (score 0):

Is this data coming from a database?  If it is then the best approach is simply have the database do the sorting for you.