# How to compare multiple dates stored inside one variable in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using **[ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com)** to create custom wordpress fields. Using the `repeater` field I can add several content using the same fields. Currently I do store two vars inside my repeater field `dates_list`:

- `si-date` – Date (format 20160225)
- `si-special` – Random text

I can store all rows of my repeater inside a var and select a certain row of `dates_list`:

```
<?php
  $rows = get_field('dates_list' ); // get all the rows
  $first_row = $rows[0]; // get the first row
  $first_row_image = $first_row['si-date' ]; // get the sub field value 
?>
```

How can I use this method to compare all dates inside `si-date` and select the row containing the next upcoming date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get the next date after today, what you could do is reference the usort function that is explained very well within here to sort you dates by most recent first: [Sorting an array with DateTime strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095351/sorting-an-array-with-datetime-strings)

Once you have sorted your array in this fashion, you could then process that array to find the first date that was greater than today. Perhaps something like:

```
foreach($sorted_dates_array as $row){
    //If the date is greater than the current time then return the row
    if(strtotime($row['si-date'])>time())
    {
        return $row;
    }
    //There are no dates that are yet to be completed
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As the $rows are already sorted by date I thought I could skip that. I get this syntax error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in … on line 1`. Are there any syntax errors in your example? I use the following code: `$rows = get_field('si-termine' ); for($rows as $row){
   if(strtotime($row['si-date'])>time())
   {
     echo "works";
   }
   echo "no more dates";
 }`

Comment: You're right Marian, there's an error in my code - that for loop should be a foreach. I've changed that for you now in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over all rows and check it "manually". I've didn't tested this code, but I think it could be a good start:

```
<?php
  $rows = get_field('dates_list');
  $actual_date = date('Ymd');
  $selected_date = '99999999';
  $selected_row = null;
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['si-date'] > $actual_date AND $row['si-date'] < $selected_date) {
        $selected_date = $row['si-date'];
        $selected_row = $row;
    }
  }
  if (is_array($selected_row)) {
    // do your stuff your with the row
  }
?>
```