# How to sort this multi-dimensional array based on notif_date_sort?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, logic

My Final array for showing notifications is like:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notification] => 1 new topic posted in : Current Affairs  classroom
            [on_create] => 12th Aug - 2016 5:20AM
            [notif_date_sort] => 2016-08-12 05:20:23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [notification] => 8 new topic posted in : GK classroom
            [on_create] => 4th Aug - 2016 10:51AM
            [notif_date_sort] => 2016-08-04 10:51:56
        )
)
```

I tried methods like multisort, ksort but didnt find proper result. How to sort this elements inside array based on "notif_date_sort" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array with DateTime strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095351/sorting-an-array-with-datetime-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with your own function to sort the results by **date**.

Like this,

```
usort($array, 'custom_date_sort');
function custom_date_sort($a,$b) {
    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a["notif_date_sort"]);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b["notif_date_sort"]);
    return $date1>$date2;
}
```

Where [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) creates the **DateTime** object from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

Try this:

```
function compare_dates($date1, $date2){
     $date1 = strtotime($date1['notif_date_sort']);
     $date2 = strtotime($date2['notif_date_sort']);
     if ($date1 == $date2) {
         return 0;
     }
     return ($date2 < $date2) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "compare_dates");
```